# NHibernate - one-to-one Cascade Settings

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a one-to-one relationship between a Person class and an Employee. I  expect the INSERT to cascade from the Person to the Employee. However, this does not happen. I've tried cascade='all' and cascade='save-update' on one-to-one relationship element, but it didn't work.

The structures of the my objects are as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual string PayRollNo { get; set; }
    public virtual int Holidays { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping files shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Employee, Employee.DAL" table="`Employee`"  >
    <id name="PersonID" column="`PersonId`" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property type="string" length="30" name="PayRollNo" column="`PayRollNo`" />
    <property type="int" name="Holidays" column="`Holidays`" />
    <one-to-one name="Person"  class="Person" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Person, Employee.DAL" table="`Person`"  >    
    <id name="PersonID" column="`PersonId`">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property" >Employee</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property type="string" name="Forename" column="`Forename`" />
    <property type="string" name="Surname" column="`Surname`" />
    <property type="int" name="Age" column="`Age`" />
    <one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee"  constrained="true"  />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code for initiating the objects and saving them:

```
var employee = new Employee();

    employee.Person = new Person { Employee = employee };

    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = (new Configuration()).Configure().BuildSessionFactory();

    employee.Person.Age = 27;
    employee.Person.Forename = "N";
    employee.Person.Surname = "M";

    employee.PayRollNo = "12";
    employee.Holidays = 27;

    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Save(employee);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the session.Save() method in a transaction. Or use the session.Flush() method after the calling the save method.

```
       using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    trans.Begin();
                    session.Save(employee);
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Nhibernate occasionally stores the SQL statements to synchronise the date in memory. The session.Flush() method commits the SQL to the database. This occurs by default on the transcation.Commit() method.

For more information refer to the Nhibernate documentation http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

Answer (score 2):

Yads is essentially right. The second `<one-to-one>` (from Employee to Person) needs `constrained="true"`. With that, the following code should work:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var person = new PersonDataContext();
    person.Employee = new EmployeeDataContext { Person = person };
    session.Save(person);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

A few additional suggestions:

- Do **not** use `lazy="false"`. Read http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/08/04/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it.aspx
- Use more DDD names for your classes. You have an entity that represents a Person, whose data is stored in the Person table. Why do you call it *PersonDataContext*?
- You are mapping to properties, not fields. Show the code for your properties in your classes instead of the underlying fields.
- You don't need to override with the default values. If a property's name is `PayRollNo`, the default column name is `PayRollNo`. If a property's type is `int`, the default mapped type is `int` too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I’ve applied all your suggestions and still it is not working, I’ve uploaded a sample source code to http://bit.ly/gNlAWr I was wondering if you have time to take a quick look at it.  Many Thanks. Nima

Comment: From reading this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775430/nhibernate-one-to-one-mapping (for which you did mark an answer) it looks like you were **not** following my instructions on the code (transaction and commit)

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone You're missing the `constrained="true"` in the `<one-to-one>` element in the Person mapping.

Comment: I’ve applied your suggestion and still it is not working, I’ve uploaded a sample source code to bit.ly/gNlAWr I was wondering if you have time to take a quick look at it.

Comment: @Nima, `contrained` attribute is on the Employee mapping, but it should be on the Person mapping. It also seems like your foreign key check should also be on the Employee table rather than the Person table.

Comment: Thanks Yads. What do you mean by foreign key check?

Comment: @Nima actually it looks like everything you have is backwards. It's the person that has the foreign key generation. It works backwards from how you would think that it works. Reread this section again, thoroughly http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone. And you likely don't need your FK constraint.

Comment: @Yads My example is a bit different to the one in the article you sent me. In my example, PersonID from Person table is PK in Person table and PK and FK on Employee table. Am I right? ;)

Comment: @Nima, they're both PKs in their respective tables. Seems like the article is doing the exact same thing, Employee is one to one with Person. However, like I said the relationship and PK assignment is backwards from what you would think. Employee actually has the native id generator and Person would have the foreign id generator. You may want to consider using joined subclass instead http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass

Comment: @Yads, At firstly I want to thank you for your patience. :) I've swapped the id settings. The person's ID is now foreign and Employee's ID is now native. I can see that it tries to insert the employee first which is wrong and results an exception.

Comment: @Yades, I've changed personID in Employee table to an Identity column and now it can correctly insert the employee. But again it inserts only employee object and it doesn't insert person. :(

Comment: @Nima, make sure you have the cascade settings set up correctly, ie Employee cascades to Person.

Comment: @Yads, I have cascade="all" in my employee calss, but still no luck. :(

Comment: @Nima, please update your question with your new mappings/entities and saving code.

Comment: @Nima, can you also show the code where you're initializing the objects and saving them?

Comment: @Nima your saving is backwards. Create the Employee and the Person objects, set Employee.Person to the created Person instance and save the Employee.

Comment: @Yads, I did what you said and still same results. It only generates on insert command for employees. I've updated the code in the question as well.

Comment: @Nima, at this point I'm stuck. The mappings and code seem correct. At this point I might recommend either using the foreign key with a unique constraint option at the bottom of the documentation for <one-to-one>, saving both the Person and Employee, or the joined subclass option

Comment: @Yades, All I needed was session.Flush()! :)

Comment: @Nima, lol ok. BTW let NHibernate autoflush, it will still guarantee that you won't get any stale data, but you should avoid calling `session.Flush` explicitly.