# NHibernate - one-to-one Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have a one-to-one relationship between a Person class and an Employee. I expect the INSERT to cascade from the Person to the Employee. However, this does not happen. I've tried cascade='all' and cascade='save-update' on one-to-one relationship element, but it didn't work. I have also uploaded my entire source code on: http://bit.ly/gnkxBr (3.52 MB)

The structures of the my objects are as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Forename { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual string PayRollNo { get; set; }
    public virtual int Holidays { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping files shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Person, Employee.DAL" table="`Person`"  >
    <id name="PersonID" column="`PersonId`" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property type="string" name="Forename" column="`Forename`" />
    <property type="string" name="Surname" column="`Surname`" />
    <property type="int" name="Age" column="`Age`" />
    <one-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" cascade="all" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Employee, Employee.DAL" table="`Employee`" >
    <id name="PersonID" column="`PersonId`">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property" >Person</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property type="string" length="30" name="PayRollNo" column="`PayRollNo`" />
    <property type="int" name="Holidays" column="`Holidays`" />
    <one-to-one name="Person"  class="Person" constrained="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the session.Save() method in a transaction. Or use the session.Flush() method after calling the save method.